# Higher-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of higher order differential equation.
$y'''-4y''-7y'+10y=0$. I know that for a differential equation of second-order, I can substitute $\lambda$ to make a quadratic equation, why does it work for higher order too?

What the concept behind?And by the way, how am I supposed to factor this?

Comment: Assume $y=e^{\lambda x}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner then it keeps piling up?

Comment: Then $(\lambda^3-4\lambda^2-7\lambda+10)e^{\lambda x}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'''-4y''-7y'+10y=0$$
Use as JW Tanner wrote in the comment $y=e^{\lambda x}$ or you can also solve it this way:
$$(y'''-y'')-3(y''-y')-10(y'-y)=0$$
$$(e^{-x}y'')'-3(e^{-x}y')'-10(e^{-x}y)'=0$$
$$y''-3y'-10y=c_1e^x$$
$$(y''+2y')-5(y'+2y)=c_1e^x$$
$$(e^{2x}y')'-5(e^{2x}y)'=c_1e^{3x}$$
$$y'-5y=c_1e^{x}+c_2e^{-2x}$$
And so on....

---

$$y'''-4y''-7y'+10y=0$$
$$ \implies (\lambda^3-4\lambda^2-7\lambda+10)=0$$
You can also factorize the polynomial in $\lambda$ since we know $\lambda=1$ is a solution:
$$P(\lambda)=
(\lambda^3-4\lambda^2-7\lambda+10)$$
$$P(\lambda)=(\lambda -1)
(\lambda^2-3\lambda-10)$$
$$P(\lambda)=(\lambda -1)(\lambda +2)
(\lambda-5)$$
$$\implies S_{\lambda}=\{1,-2,5\}$$

Comment: you were missing a x for $y=e^{\lambda}$

Comment: Oh thans @shine Corrected.